# print Json from mongoDB

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, web-services

I tried to print my json from mongoDB.
I have one file(index.js) that call to function(getAllStudent) that exists in other file (student.js)and need to print my json, but it dosent work. when i run it in URL (in web page) its said me:"Cannot GET /getAllStudent".

My code:

index.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://db_usr:db_p');

var conn=mongoose.connection;
conn.on('error',function(err){
    console.log('connection error'+err);
});

conn.once('open',function(){
    console.log('connected.');
    mongoose.disconnect();
});
```

student.js

```
var express=require('express');
var app=express();
var fs=require('fs');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var schema = mongoose.Schema;
var userSchema = new schema({
      name:{type:String},
      id: Number,
      grade: Number,
      year: Number,
      coures:{type:String}
  },  {collection: 'json'});

var User= mongoose.model('student',userSchema);
module.exports=User;

//return all students in json

module.exports = function(app) { 
   app.get('/getAllStudent', function(req,res) {
    student.find({},function(err,user){
            if(err) throw err;
            console.log(User);
            mongoose.disconnect();
        });
    })
```

Comment: You are using wrong name .use User instead of student.

Comment: I fix it but it still dosent work

Comment: you are exporting two things in one js file .I think this is wrong